# Setting a page number from the URL, with fallbacks

Tags: performance, beginner, url, coldfusion, cfml

I have the following code, but it somehow looks a bit redundant.
As I am new to ColdFusion, I am not sure how to optimize it. Can someone suggest an alternative?

```
<cfparam name="url.idInfopage" default="0">
<cfif  not isNumeric(url.idInfopage)><cfset url.idInfopage= 0></cfif>

<cfif isDefined("stElement.idInfopage") and isNumeric(stElement.idInfopage)>
    <cfset idInfopage= stElement.idInfopage>
    <cfif  idInfopage is ""><cfset idInfopage= 0></cfif> 
<cfelse>
    <cfset idInfopage= url.idInfopage>
</cfif>
```

Comment: What version of CF are you running?

Comment: I am using MX7 at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could re-write it something like this:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(stElement,'idInfoPage') AND isNumeric(stElement.idInfopage)>
    <cfset idInfopage = stElement.idInfopage />

<cfelseif StructKeyExists(Url,'idInfoPage') AND isNumeric(Url.idInfopage)>
    <cfset idInfopage = Url.idInfopage />

<cfelse>
    <cfset idInfopage = 0 />

</cfif>
```

Notes on the changes:

- [StructKeyExists](http://cfdocs.org/StructKeyExists) is generally recommended over [isDefined](http://cfdocs.org/isDefined).
- [isNumeric](http://cfdocs.org/isNumeric) wont return true for empty string.

If you have a lot of code like this, it might make sense to create a function, something like:

```
<cfset idInfopage = getNumberOrZero('idInfopage',stElement,Url) />
```

Then implemented as:

```
<cffunction name="getNumberOrZero" returntype="numeric" output=false
    hint="Loops through structs (args 2..n) looking for number; else return 0">
    <cfargument name="Key" type="String" required />
    <cfset var i = 0 />

    <cfloop index="i" from=2 to=#ArrayLen(Arguments)#>
        <cfif StructKeyExists(Arguments[i],Arguments.Key)
            AND isNumeric(Arguments[i][Arguments.Key])
            >
            <cfreturn Arguments[i][Arguments.Key] />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn 0 />
</cffunction>
```